# CVS command to get all the version numbers of a file?

Tags: eclipse, cvs

A CVS Repository is of `:pserver`.. type.

Is there a cvs command that will retrieve a list of all versions of **one** particular file in the repository? Something that works like the CVS eclipse plugin's :

```
right click on a source file -> Team -> Show History
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to do it via:

```
cvs log fileName
```